# Twig - Dynamic Template Include

Tags: twig

I need to include templates with dynamic names:

I tried:

```
{% for plugin in plugins %}
    {% include 'plugins/{{ plugin.name }}/navbar_left.tpl' %}
{% endfor %}
```

But then it shows:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message
>   'Unable to find template "plugins/{{ plugin.name }}/navbar_left.tpl"

As you can see it doesn't replace `{{ plugin.name }}`. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It works like this:

```
{% include 'plugins/' ~ plugin.name ~ '/navbar_left.tpl' %}
```

As `~` concats strings in Twig.